# How to prevent the checkbox for getting unchecked for a sec' while navigating to next page in angular

Tags: html, angular, checkbox

The checkbox is getting unchecked when loading is happen while navigating to the next page, this is happening only for a second and it gets checked

```
<td>
                    <input
                      #addressChecklist
                      type="checkbox"
                      class="checkbox"
                      id="test"
                      [value]="card.address.id"
                      [checked]="saveAddress && saveAddress == card.address.id"
                      (change)="
                        selectThisAddress(
                          addressChecklist.value,
                          card.address.id,  
                          card.address,   
                          $event   
                        )
                      "    
                    />
                  </td>
```

Comment: We probably need the .ts to help you. You are probably resetting your saveAddress variable before navigating or something like this.